# Create Altair chart with grouped dates by week in X axis

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair

```
DATE,AMOUNT
2022-04-05,100
2022-04-06,10
2022-04-07,90
2022-04-08,75
2022-04-12,32
2022-04-13,400
2022-04-14,28
2022-04-15,50
```

With a dataset like this, how can I create a bar chart grouped by week so the X axis shows only two bars, `april 03 - april 09` and `april 11 - april 17`? (Taking into account that the week starts on sundays, even tho there is no data for dates like `april 04`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [time units in VegaLite](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/timeunit.html) to group observations. `week()` will return the week number, but I am not sure there is a way to format the label the way you want without doing it manually via `labelExpr` as I have done below.

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')

alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='AMOUNT',
    y=alt.Y(
        'week(DATE):O', axis=alt.Axis(
            labelExpr="datum.label == 'W14' ? 'Apr 04 - Apr 10' : 'Apr 11 - Apr 17'")
   )
)
```

[image]

You could also compute the labels via pandas first, which is more automatic than the above:

```py
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df_by_week = df.resample('W', on ='DATE').sum().reset_index()
df_by_week['date_label'] = df_by_week['DATE'].apply(
    lambda x: f'{(x - pd.Timedelta(days=6)).strftime("%b %d")} - {x.strftime("%B %d")}'
)
alt.Chart(df_by_week).mark_bar().encode(
    x='AMOUNT',
    y='date_label'
)
```

[image]